# Retrieving next Image(s) from Database using ArrayList Java

Tags: java, sqlite, user-interface, arraylist

I'm able to retrieve the first image from the database from ResultSet when JButton is clicked like so:

```
    if(rs.next()){
        byte[] imageQues = rs.getBytes("questionDesc");
        imageQuestion = new ImageIcon(imageQues);
        lblQuestionDesc.setIcon(imageQuestion);
}
```

But assuming I want to read these Images through an **`ArrayList`** and display the next **`n`** Images, I'm not sure if this is correct:

```
public class Images {
    private byte[] question;

    public Images(byte[] _question){

        this.question = _question;
    }
    public byte[] getQuestion(){
        return this.question;
    }
```

Another ArrayList I have displays each question (as text) with no problem like so:

```
public static List<Questions> BindList(){
    try{
        //Get a connection
        //Create Statement...
        //Declare ArrayList
        List<Questions> list = new ArrayList<Questions>();

        while(rs.next()){
            Questions ques = new Questions(rs.getString("questionDesc"));
            list.add(ques);
        }
        return list;
    }catch(SQLException ex1){
    //Exception stuff
    }
    return null;
}
public void ShowQuestions(int index){
    lblQuestion.setText(BindList().get(index).getQuestion());
}
```

My question is... Is it possible to display images in the same way as I can display the text? And how could I do this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: How can the same field in the database hold text as well as image? Are you sure the images and text are both stored in `questionDesc` column? Also, I am really not sure what your question is?

Comment: Do you want know how to display the image from what you got from the database?

Comment: @bot, Sorry, I should have mentioned those are just two separate tables (solely for demonstration purposes), one holds text, the other holds images. I was able to retrieve text from the ArrayList but am not sure how to retrieve images from it.

Comment: And @Eranda, I can display the first image by clicking a button, but wasn't sure how to loop through more than one image record in an ArrayList! I know it's probably basic enough...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using if condition for the fetched data so you are not iterating further. If there are more than one row use while loop to iterate all rows.

```
List<Images> imgList = new ArrayList<Images>();
while(rs.next()){
       Images img = new Images(rs.getBytes("questionDesc"));
       imgList.add(img);
       imageQuestion = new ImageIcon(img);
       lblQuestionDesc.setIcon(imageQuestion);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment.. However, I'm getting an error `The method add(byte[]) in the type ArrayList<byte[]> is not applicable for the arguments (Images)`